# Formatação de um double em Java

Tags: java, formatação

Como manter a variável `double` com 2 casas após a virgula?

Abaixo tenho um exemplo, ao transformar uma `String` em `double` caso ela tenha valores após o ponto é mantido as 2 casas, no entanto caso seja somente zeros, não.

```
"10.01" => 10.01
"10.00" => 10.0  //Gostaria do resultado 10.00
```

Comment: Você quer formatar o `double` de volta para uma `String` com as duas casas decimais correto? O formato interno do `double` é fixo, porém, para questões de exibição é possível formatar sim.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
String resultado = String.format("%.2f", valor);
```

Ou também pode fazer assim:

```
double numero= 10.00;
DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#.##");      
numero = Double.valueOf(formato.format(numero));
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda me ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 6):

Use também o `.setscale()`

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(< tipo >);

bd.setscale(< qtdCasas >);
```

Comment: Mas ai deixa de ser `double`. Pelo que entendi, é transformar uma `String` em `double` sem perder os decimais.

Answer (score 6):

A resposta do Franchesco está estritamente correta. Estou postando algo apenas para esclarecer algo importante que não consta em lugar algum e a pergunta parece popular e pode ensinar errado.

Este número parece ser um valor monetário. O tipo `double` não é adequado para armazenar valores monetários ou outros que exijam exatidão. Pode ver mais em [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Portanto a resposta do user58415, apesar do erro de digitação, é até mais adequada se considerar a necessidade de exatidão. Para valores exatos em Java use o [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Com o tipo correto pode aplicar a formatação que desejar. Não faça o mesmo erro que até bancos cometem publicamente, aprenda a programar corretamente!

```
import java.math.*;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        BigDecimal valor = new BigDecimal("10.00");
        valor.setScale(2);
        System.out.println(valor);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7su49O). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/ojkevlllup-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/FormatBigDecimal.java).

Answer (score -2):

String str = "10.00";
//Ainda que a entrada fosse str="10.0" a saída seria "10.00" formatada
double d = Double.parseDouble(str);

System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", d));