# Preencher double zero a esquerda em java

Tags: java, decimal, number-format, double

Gostaria de saber como faço para formatar um doouble com duas casas a esquerda do ponto e duas a direita do ponto.

Exemplo: tenho o double 1.1

quero que seja formatado para 01.10;

entrada: 10.1 / 1.05

saída : 10.01 / 01.05

Comment: Possível duplicata de  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30701/formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-double-em-java?rq=1

Comment: Na verdade eu queria que o double fosse formatado e não uma string. Quando utilizo o exemplo citado no tópico linkado está formatando para 10.0, quando queria que formatasse para 10.00. 


DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        numero = Double.valueOf(formato.format(numero));
         System.out.println(numero);

saída: 10.0

Comment: Preciso ordenar os valores do double 01.20 é maior do que 01.11 mas está considerando 01.2 ,com isso a ordenação fica errada.

Comment: Isso que tu falou não faz sentido. `1.2 > 1.11` na matemática, não é porque tá faltando um zero que o 1.11 é maior. Double é um número, zeros a esquerda não fazem diferença em nenhuma operação, assim como os zeros a direita após a vírgula também não.

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu. O sistema carrega uma lista de números decimais. [1.5; 1.10; 1.15; 2.5] quando faço a ordenação desses números  ordena da seguinte forma: [1.1; 1.15;1.5;2.5] , ou seja, o zero do 1.10 foi desconciderado.

Comment: Sim, porque zero a direita após a vírgula não interfere em nada. A ordenação está perfeita. Não to entendendo que resultado que você quer.

Comment: O problema é que [1.10 ; 1.9 ; 1.0]  está ficando [1.0 ; 1.1 ; 1.9], minha dúvida é como faço para considerar 1.10 e não 1.1

Comment: Faz virar inteiro na ordenação então. Digo, `110 > 19 > 10`, imagino que é isso que você quer.

Comment: Obrigado cara! transformei num inteiro e deu certo.