# Como limitar o número de casas decimais em Java

Tags: java

Olá, nesse trecho eu pego um valor double multiplico a 0.3 e exibo num textview, como mostro o resultado com 2 casas decimais?

```
deslocamento.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try{
                if (deslocamento.isChecked()){
                    double valorDeslocamento1 = Double.parseDouble(valorViagem.getText().toString())*0.3;
                    valorDeslocamento.setText( String.valueOf(valorDeslocamento1));
            }
        }
    } );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatação de um double em java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30701/formata%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-um-double-em-java)

Answer (score 1):

NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0,00");
System.out.println(formatter.format(2.0));

Comment: Paulo muito Obrigado Deus abençoe vc

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView tv = //sua textView
String value = tv.getText().toString();
double n = Double.parseDouble(value) * 0.3;
String result = String.format("%.2f", n);
//.2 é a precisão do número e %f é a máscara para números de ponto flutuante
```

Comment: Pedro muito Obrigado viu Deus te abençoe.