# Formatar um double de uma variável com duas casas

Tags: java, variáveis, formatação

Tenho um número em Double vindo de um objeto (acho) e será exibido em uma tabela *abstractTable*. Gostaria que fosse exibido com apenas duas casas após o ponto. Meu código abaixo:

```
public Double preco = 1.0; 
public Double precoDesconto = 1.0;
int desconto = rs.getInt("desconto");
System.out.println("Após verificar na DAO, o desconto é: " + desconto);

if (desconto == 1) {
    precoDesconto = preco * 0.3847;
} else if (desconto == 2) {
    precoDesconto = preco * 0.405;
}

try {                
    return dados.get(linha).getPreco() * getDesconto(getDesconto(precoDesconto));
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("\n" + this + " Erro ao obter preco com desconto: " + ex);
}
```

Observação: Estou calculando a porcentagem de desconto de um produto com preço `preco` e cada usuário terá um desconto diferente `desconto`. O preço com desconto está expresso em `precoDesconto`.

Comment: Deve te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30701/formatação-de-um-double-em-java

Answer (score 0):

Existem duas soluções.

1° solução:

```
String resultadoFormatado = String.format("%.2f", precoDesconto);
```

2° solução:

```
DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double resultadoFormatado = Double.valueOf(formato.format(precoDesconto));
```

Answer (score -1):

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Format {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double integerDouble1 = (2.345);
    Double integerDouble2 = new Double(2.345);

    System.out.println("# Inteiro Duplo sem Formatação (" + integerDouble1 + ")");

    //Neste exemplo (integerDouble1), o Inteiro Duplo é implementado como sendo uma Variável  
    System.out.println("# Exemplo (1): Inteiro Duplo com Formatação (1) >>> (" + (new DecimalFormat("#.##")).format(integerDouble1) + ")");
    System.out.println("# Exemplo (1): Inteiro Duplo com Formatação (2) >>> (" + String.format("%.2f", integerDouble1) + ")");

    //Neste exemplo (integerDouble2), o Inteiro Duplo é implementado como sendo um Objeto da Classe (wrapper) Double  
    System.out.println("# Exemplo (2): Inteiro Duplo com Formatação (1) >>> (" + (new DecimalFormat("#.##")).format(integerDouble2) + ")");
    System.out.println("# Exemplo (2): Inteiro Duplo com Formatação (2) >>> (" + String.format("%.2f", integerDouble2) + ")");

}
```

}